# How to get gradle to compile local version of picasso

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android project that uses a local version of the [picasso library](https://github.com/square/picasso) that I have modified in a few ways. However, whenever I try to build my project from the command line using `gradle build`, I always get an error that Picasso does not exist:

```
$ ./gradlew build 
:compileLint
:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/me/project/src/com/example/myproject/MyView.java:30: error: package com.squareup.picasso does not exist
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
```

Moreover, when I run with `--info`, I can see it is assembling tasks, but the `picasso:check` and `picasso:build` are incorrectly placed at the end:

`Tasks to be executed: [task ':compileLint', task ':copyDebugLint', task ':mergeDebugProguardFiles', task ':preBuild', task ':preDebugBuild', task ':checkDebugManifest', task ':prepareDebugDependencies', task ':compileDebugAidl', task ':compileDebugRenderscript', task ':generateDebugBuildConfig', task ':generateDebugAssets', task ':mergeDebugAssets', task ':generateDebugResValues', task ':generateDebugResources', task ':packageDebugResources', task ':processDebugManifest', task ':processDebugResources', task ':generateDebugSources', task ':processDebugJavaRes', task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac', task ':packageDebugJar', task ':compileDebugNdk', task ':packageDebugJniLibs', task ':packageDebugLocalJar', task ':packageDebugRenderscript', task ':bundleDebug', task ':compileDebugSources', task ':assembleDebug', task ':copyReleaseLint', task ':mergeReleaseProguardFiles', task ':preReleaseBuild', task ':checkReleaseManifest', task ':prepareReleaseDependencies', task ':compileReleaseAidl', task ':compileReleaseRenderscript', task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig', task ':generateReleaseAssets', task ':mergeReleaseAssets', task ':generateReleaseResValues', task ':generateReleaseResources', task ':packageReleaseResources', task ':processReleaseManifest', task ':processReleaseResources', task ':generateReleaseSources', task ':processReleaseJavaRes', task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac', task ':packageReleaseJar', task ':compileReleaseNdk', task ':packageReleaseJniLibs', task ':packageReleaseLocalJar', task ':packageReleaseRenderscript', task ':bundleRelease', task ':compileReleaseSources', task ':assembleRelease', task ':assemble', task ':lint', task ':preDebugUnitTestBuild', task ':prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies', task ':processDebugUnitTestJavaRes', task ':compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac', task ':compileDebugUnitTestSources', task ':mockableAndroidJar', task ':assembleDebugUnitTest', task ':testDebugUnitTest', task ':preReleaseUnitTestBuild', task ':prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies', task ':processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes', task ':compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac', task ':compileReleaseUnitTestSources', task ':assembleReleaseUnitTest', task ':testReleaseUnitTest', task ':test', task ':check', task ':build', task ':android-autofittextview:assemble', task ':android-autofittextview:check', task ':android-autofittextview:build', task ':picasso:assemble', task ':picasso:check', task ':picasso:build']`

I would think that `:picasso:(assemble|check|build)` would need to be run prior to `:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`, which it is failing on, especially given my `compile project(':picasso')` directive in the dependencies section of my build.gradle file.

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    sourceSets {
      main {
          manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
          java.srcDirs = ['src']
          resources.srcDirs = ['src']
          aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
          renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
          res.srcDirs = ['res']
          assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      }
    }

}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    compile project(':picasso')
    compile project(':android-autofittextview')
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
}
```

And here is my `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':myproject'

include ':picasso'
project(':picasso').projectDir = \
  new File(settingsDir, '../../../Lib/picasso')

include ':android-autofittextview'
project(':android-autofittextview').projectDir = \
  new File(settingsDir, '../../../Interface/android-autofittextview')
```

Here is my gradle version:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-09-14 07:26:16 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     c41505168da69fb0650f4e31c9e01b50ffc97893

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 25.51-b03)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64
```

Note that I do not believe this has anything to do with picasso itself because I see the same problem trying to compile a local version of [android-autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) too.

Can anyone tell me how I can get gradle to properly compile and include my local version of picasso?

---

Shot in the dark, but I wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that my android-library projects are building [.aar](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) files and not .jar files, and so somehow gradle doesn't recognize these as valid dependencies?

Comment: Make sure that the gradle file in the picasso project has the same compileSdkVersion and the buildToolsVersion as your project

Comment: @eric247 I just ensured they match, no effect.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Not yet. I am trying to compile from the command line of OSX first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to successfully build. Picasso has a project structure where there is a root directory and then numerous subdirectories, each representing different projects (picasso, picasso-sample, picasso-pollexor). I was setting the projectDir to be the root picasso directory instead of the actual library subdirectory. Thus, I changed my settings.gradle file from this:

```
project(':picasso').projectDir = \
  new File(settingsDir, '../../../Lib/picasso')
```

to this

```
project(':picasso').projectDir = \
  new File(settingsDir, '../../../Lib/picasso/picasso')
```

I did a similar thing in one of my other dependencies. Thus, instead of:

```
project(':android-autofittextview').projectDir = \
  new File(settingsDir, '../../Interface/android-autofittextview')
```

I did this:

```
project(':android-autofittextview').projectDir = \
  new File(settingsDir, '../../Interface/android-autofittextview/library')
```

It's tricky because in this latter example, the build.gradle file in the library directory had dependencies on the parent build.gradle that I had to copy down into the child. Seems like I should be able to create a dependency on the parent project that understands I mean the child /library.

But ultimately I was able to get it to compile using this approach.